# How to use a Component with Admin Generator?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I know we can use components with the admin generator (thanks to ~ symbol).

However, in the components.class.php, how to call the auto-generated class ?

At this moment, I'm using this :

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/commissionGeneratorConfiguration.class.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/commissionGeneratorHelper.class.php';


class commissionComponents extends autoCommissionComponents
{

}
```

But I obtain this error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'autoCommissionComponents' not found in /home/site/liguelorraine/apps/saSecureLigueLorraine/modules/commission/actions/components.class.php on line 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no automatically generated component classes. Just extends `sfComponents` as usual.